# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I first installed and loaded **tensorflow** and **keras** without issues.

When I try to load the MNIST-database, however, I get the following error:

> Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

```
install.packages(c("tensorflow", "keras"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

Answer (score 1):

https://keras.rstudio.com/ mentions a different approach:

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

Comment: thanks Rob, unfortunately. I now get another error: 
Creating r-tensorflow conda environment for TensorFlow installation...
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL (...) VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000004FAD630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))",),)
Error: Error 1 occurred creating conda environment r-tensorflow

Comment: Seems to me (although I am not completely sure) keras tried to create a virtual environment to install keras and tensorflow but fails to do so. Are you on windows? If so you need to install conda first : https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/reference/install_keras.html

Comment: I already had conda installed. The same error happens whether I use install_keras(method = "conda") or just install_keras().

Comment: You might need to uninstall any previous keras versions and make a fresh install. This worked for me.

Comment: Uninstalled keras and tensorflow. Restarted computer. Same issue unfortunately.